# "composer install" it doesn't install laravel/ui dependency

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, composer-php

I'm don't know much about nodejs or npm dependencies, so any insights will be helpful.

We have a CI that builds our docker images, we have a multi build stage that uses a node image to run "npm install", so far so good. Also in the next build stage, we use a composer image that runs `composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --no-autoloader --prefer-dist` and makes use of the dependencies listed on `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files. All dependencies are installed, except for the `lavarel/ui`, which composer seems just to ignore its existence from the file.

Consequently soon in the build an error occurs when running `composer dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize`, telling that `laravel/ui` must be installed, (see the error output below).

```
  ---> Running in 68b542e7f182
 Generating optimized autoload files
 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
 > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
 In Auth.php line 56:
                                                                                
   In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui pa  
   ckage.                                                                       
                                                                                
 Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
 The command '/bin/sh -c composer dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

composer.json -- As I said all dependencies listed on `require` are installed, excepts `laravel/ui`. The problem is the same if I set `laravel/ui` on `require-dev`.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        .
        .
        .
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "lucascudo/laravel-pt-br-localization": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
```

composer.lock

```
{
            "name": "laravel/ui",
            "version": "v2.0.3",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/laravel/ui.git",
                "reference": "15368c5328efb7ce94f35ca750acde9b496ab1b1"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/ui/zipball/15368c5328efb7ce94f35ca750acde9b496ab1b1",
                "reference": "15368c5328efb7ce94f35ca750acde9b496ab1b1",
                "shasum": ""
            },
```

Does anyone have some idea of what is could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I tried running `composer update laravel/ui` and some packages in the `composer.lock`, including `laravel/ui`, were updated, after that the docker build finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use laravel default auth then laravel/ui package is required.

For more details visit: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

You should delete your vender directory and composer-lock.json file.

Then run `composer install` command, it might solve your error.

Comment: Thank you SJR, I did as you suggest but the result was the same.